# Difference between "therapy" and "treatment"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *therapy* and *treatment*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have a close meaning, but "treatment" is more about a series of drugs prescribed, while "therapy" is a wider term. The second encompasses other aspects of health, such as psychological or therapeutical help.